# How can I access the closest <Route>'s match inside children?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I'm rendering with `ReactDom` in an index.js file.

```js
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <HashRouter>
            <Route path="/:myParam">
                <Switch>
                    <SomeProvider myParam={HOW_TO_ACCESS_MY_PARAM_HERE}>
                        <Route path="/:myParam/home" component={Home}/>
                        <Route path="/:myParam/test" component={MyTest}/>
                    </SomeProvider>
                </Switch>
            </Route>
        </HashRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I'm looking a way to pass `route param` as a prop to `SomeProvider`

There's always `myParam` and it's avaiable in `Home` and `MyTest` components as `this.props.match.params.myParam`, but I need to access it inside children of first `Route`.

Is there a way I can get it there? In an entry point file, not component.

Answer (score 1):

You can access `match` from any child of a `<Route>` by using [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter):

```js
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

class SomeProvider extends Component {
  ...
  render() {
    const myParam = this.props.match.params.myParam;
    ...
  }
}

export default withRouter(SomeProvider)
```

In doing so, you won't need to pass `myParam` as a prop.